# For Loop inside Caesar Cipher VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I found this Caesar cipher code and am just trying to fully understand it, I get how the cipher itself works as it takes the first letter within the message string, and what ever number the user enters as the key it goes through the alphabet from the first letter in the string that many times and whichever letter it lands on it replaces each individual letter within the string with the letter the key chose.

Its just the code itself i am having a bit of trouble with, specifically the for loop so if anybody could explain how the for loop works i would be very grateful, thanks. Here is the code:

```
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine(Encrypt)

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
Function Encrypt() As String

    Dim Key As Integer
    Dim Message As String
    Dim EncMessage As String
    Console.Write("Please enter a message that you would like to encrypt: ")
    Message = Console.ReadLine  ' user inputs the message they wish to encrypt

    Dim LetterArray() As Char = Message.ToCharArray  ' 
    Console.Write("What key would you like to use?: ")
    Key = Console.ReadLine()

    For i = 0 To LetterArray.Length - 1
        EncMessage = EncMessage & Chr(Asc(LetterArray) + Key)
    Next

    Return EncMessage

End Function
```

Comment: you want us to explain *your* code to *you*?

Comment: I said i _found_ the code

Comment: That code is not doing a Caesar cipher in the way a Caesar cipher is understood to operate. Try the code at [stackoverflow.com/a/26920472/1115360](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26920472/1115360).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Lbound() and Ubound() to navigate arrays. Also, I do not see i reserved anywhere. You also should have the function return the value through the function itself

```
For i = Lbound(LetterArray) to Ubound(LetterArray)-1
EncMessage = ...your cipher thing here
Next

Encrypt = EncMessage
```