# How to advance string 3 letters in the alphabet (Caesar cipher)?

Tags: string, vb.net, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to make a program that encrypts a string the user submits. I want to use an encryption technique where the string is advanced 3 letters in the alphabet.
Example: `abc` would become `def`.
Currently I have a TextBox (`TextBox1`) and a Button (`Button1`).
My code so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rawText As String
    rawText = TextBox1.Text
    Dim letterTxt As String = Chr(Asc(rawText) + 3)
    MsgBox(letterTxt)

End Sub
```

The problem is that when I run it, it only outputs 1 letter.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: you need a for loop to run over each character to build your result.

Comment: Also, use `ASCW()` and `CHRW()` as we now work in a Unicode, not ASCII world.

Comment: `XYZ` and `xyz` will become `[ \ ]` and `{ | } `. Is that a viable option? Or you want to start back at `A, a`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am having trouble making a loop for a Caesar cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917977/i-am-having-trouble-making-a-loop-for-a-caesar-cipher)

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it's _**not encryption**_. It might just barely qualify as a cipher. .Net has several real encryption algorithms built in. You should look at one of those.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts. Yes, Unicode, as of VB4 (1995)!

Comment: What comes after a Zero Width non breaking space or 日本語？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) method. Accepts positive and negative shifts and, optionally, a number of alphabet letters.
The latter, to be tested with ASCII tables different than the usual US-ASCII.

*It doesn't alter digits* (skipped) but you can modify it using the same pattern, if needed.

Use the `Scramble` parameter to select scramble (True) or unscramble (False).

Sample test code:

```vb
Dim Scrambled1 As String = CaesarCipher("ABCXYZabcxyz", 3, True)
Dim Scrambled2 As String = CaesarCipher("ABCXYZabcxyz", -5, True)

'Scrambled1 is now DEFABCdefabc
'Scrambled2 is now VWXSTUvwxstu

Dim Unscrambled As String = CaesarCipher(Scrambled2, -5, false)

'Unscrambled is now ABCXYZabcxyz
```

---

```vb
Function CaesarCipher(Input As String, CaesarShift As Integer, Scramble As Boolean, Optional AlphabetLetters As Integer = 26) As String

    Dim CharValue As Integer
    Dim MinValue As Integer = AscW("A"c)
    Dim MaxValue As Integer = AscW("Z"c)
    Dim ScrambleMode As Integer = If((Scramble), 1, -1)
    Dim output As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(Input.Length)

    If Math.Abs(CaesarShift) >= AlphabetLetters Then
        CaesarShift = (AlphabetLetters * Math.Sign(CaesarShift)) - Math.Sign(CaesarShift)
    End If

    For Each c As Char In Input
        CharValue = AscW(c)
        If Not Char.IsNumber(c) Then
            CharValue = CharValue + (CaesarShift * ScrambleMode) Mod AlphabetLetters
            CharValue = If(AscW(Char.ToUpper(c)) + (CaesarShift * ScrambleMode) > MaxValue, CharValue - AlphabetLetters, CharValue)
            CharValue = If(AscW(Char.ToUpper(c)) + (CaesarShift * ScrambleMode) < MinValue, CharValue + AlphabetLetters, CharValue)
        End If
        output.Append(ChrW(CharValue))
    Next
    Return output.ToString()
End Function
```