# How do I make this work for both lower and upper case characters?

Tags: vb.net

I need help with some college homework here (yes, they teach us vb.net in 2019).

So, I need to create a program that takes each character from an user generated text and changes it to a character that is equal to "Chr(Asc(OriginalCharacter) + N)".

If, for example, that number leads to a character greater than the last character of the alphabet, it should go all the way back to the beginning of it and count (let's say it's lower case) (Asc(OriginalCharacter) + N - 122) from there.

I've managed to successfully do it for any given number N, but I can only do it if I make OriginalText.ToLower

Here's my code (the variables and stuff are written in Portuguese):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Frase As String = InputBox("Frase: ")
    Dim NumChars As Integer = Len(Frase)
    Dim N As Integer = InputBox("Numero: ")
    Dim NovaFrase As String = ""
    Dim CharNum As Integer = 0
    Dim temp As Integer = 0

    Frase = Trim(Frase.ToLower)

    For i = 1 To NumChars
        CharNum = 0
        If Asc(Mid(Frase, i, 1)) = 32 Then
            CharNum = Asc(Mid(Frase, i, 1))
            NovaFrase = NovaFrase & Chr(CharNum)
        ElseIf Asc(Mid(Frase, i, 1)) + N >= 97 Then
            CharNum = Asc(Mid(Frase, i, 1)) + N
            'MsgBox("charnum: " & CharNum)
            While CharNum > 122
                temp = CharNum - 122
                '   MsgBox("temp: " & temp)
                CharNum = 96 + temp
                '  MsgBox("charnum: " & CharNum)
            End While
        End If
        NovaFrase = NovaFrase & Chr(CharNum)
        MsgBox(NovaFrase)
    Next
End Sub
```

Also, I would be really grateful if you could give me feedback on what I could do better :)

Studying for my finals... -_-

P.S.: when answering, please keep in mind that I'm not doing any Computer Science focused course, it's Management Engineering :)

Comment: *"yes, they teach us vb.net in 2019"*.  The problem is not that they teach you VB.NET.  VB.NET is a perfectly modern programming language.  The problem is that they are still teaching it like it was VB6 from 20 years ago.  That code is horrible.  You might also consider adding some comments to it.

Comment: What it's doing is known as a Caesar cipher. There are a few code examples here on Stack Overflow, e.g. [I am having trouble making a loop for a Caesar cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26920472/1115360).

Comment: @jmcilhinney more like VB3 than VB4/5/6. @ACGarcia00, `Asc` and `Chr` probably don't do what you think they do and probably aren't wanted. Use `AscW` and `ChrW` instead. .NET uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set for text datatypes.

Comment: Wow, that doesn't sound good at all! xD

Thank goodness I'm going back to my engineering college in Brazil by the first week of February. My teacher was years ahead from this one here in Portugal. I can't believe I'm in what is considered the best engineering school in this country and they teach code worse than a developing country lol. I actually think the course was overall better there tbh.

Comment: p.s.: in Brazil I was being teach Python and would later learn Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). You'll see that lower case letters are from 97 to 122. You did that part correctly. You can then notice that upper case are from 65 to 90. So you just need to handle those case.

```
Dim currentCharacter As Integer = Asc(Mid(Frase, i, 1))

If currentCharacter >= 97 AndAlso currentCharacter <= 122 Then
  ' ...
Else If currentCharacter >= 65 AndAlso currentCharacter <= 90 Then
  ' ...
End If
```

Also, VB.NET is very different than VB. It is a very good language and still being updated in 2019. A lot of method that you are using aren't really vb.net but part of the old vb.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate =)